# Filtering GNU split with a custom shell function

Tags: bash, split

Is there a way to use GNU split `--filter` with a custom shell function, like

```
my_func () {
  echo $1
}
split -d 10 INPUT_FILE chunk_ --filter="my_func $FILE$"
```

which I would expect to output

```
chunk_00
chunk_01
...
```

Of course the echo in the custom func is just for expressing my question here, in my concrete case the custom function creates a script that uses the chunks from split as input.

It seems that GNU shell only accepts standard shell commands within `--filter`.

Any smart way around this?

Comment: The command `split -d INPUT_FILE chunk_` outputs the expected file format. It's not clear to me if you want use `--filter` to modify the filename or you want to perform some action on each chunk. In both cases, please update your question.

Comment: Just put your function into a script.

Comment: The true function performs builds a shell scripts where the chunk is used as argument to another command.

Comment: If I put the function into a script I will need to update the PATH, this defeats the ease of use I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You can prefix the command in the filter argument with either a relative or absolute path. There is no need to update `PATH`. i.e. `--filter="/some/path/my_func.sh $FILE"` works perfectly fine.

Comment: yes ok. It is one way out. Still I would have preferred to keep this subscript inline inside the user script. But I guess there is no mechanism for introspection. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by exporting the function to the environment, which is available to the sub-shell run by split. For example with bash:

*ex.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

my_func() {
  echo $1
}

export -f my_func

seq inf | split -d --filter='my_func $FILE' /dev/stdin chunk_
```

If you run it like this:

```
bash ex.sh | head
```

The output is:

```
chunk_00
chunk_01
chunk_02
chunk_03
chunk_04
chunk_05
chunk_06
chunk_07
chunk_08
chunk_09
```

More details in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233097/17666) on UL.

Note that `split` uses whatever the `SHELL` variable is set to as the sub-shell to run the `--filter` command. If you are running a different shell, you may need to add `export SHELL=/bin/bash` before running `split`.